# Unable to query this XML response using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap

First of all sorry that I am very well aware that similar kind of questions have been posted by many and I have gone through that but I could not find the solution out of it for me.

Though I have used XPath in few other programs without any issue but for this, I couldn't generate correct XPath.
Since I was not able to implement using SAAJ as it needed SSL certificate to connect because of https URL for the Webservice. 
So has to go for HttpClient and the output is as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getBalanceResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.soap.xyzservice.com">
            <ns:return xmlns:ax23="http://dto.soap.xyzservice.com/xsd" type="com.valuecardservice.soap.dto.abcxyz">            
                <ax23:errorMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />               
                <ax23:resultCode>200</ax23:resultCode>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:getBalanceResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have added namespace context and also

```
    doc.setNamespaceAware(true);

    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals("soapenv"))
                return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
            if (prefix.equals("ns"))
                return "http://services.soap.xyzservice.com";
            if (prefix.equals("ax23"))
                return "http://http://dto.soap.xyzservice.com/xsd";

            return null;
        }
    });


    // xpath evaluate code to parse  
    Node resultCdNode = ((NodeList) xpath.evaluate( 
        "//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getBalanceResponse/ns:return/ax23:resultCode/text()", 
        root, 
        XPathConstants.NODESET) 
    ).item(0);
```

This return null. I tried different xpath but no use, everything is retuning null.

I tried many options and then I came to know this tool though not sure whether its working correct or not

http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html

In this I tried to generate xpath using the above xml. I couldn't able to generate path after the below mentioned xpath.
It doesn't showing up any option.

```
soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getBalanceResponse/
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with xpath. What is the correct xpath to get the `resultCode`'s value?

Comment: Try not specifying `http://` twice for the `ax23` prefix in the `getNamespaceURI()` method.

Comment: Oh...It works...Feeling very bad for spending 4 hrs without finding this silly mistake...

Comment: If that solved your problem you can self-answer the question and then accept your own answer (after a short waiting period) which will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Since the problem was a simple typo, it is considered off-topic for StackOverflow, given that nobody else will benefit from the answer. As such, you should really just delete the question, but I've added the answer for you to accept, if you think others would benefit from your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you accidentally specified `http://` twice for the `ax23` prefix in the `getNamespaceURI()` method.